# HighCharts render chart already zoomed

Tags: javascript, highcharts, zooming

Is it possible to render a zoomable charts and have it already zoomed. I'm using a scatter plot which is zoomable on the x and y axis and would like to have it rendered already zoomed in to certain values.

Is there any default zooming options I can set when defining the chart?

Here is a working example of the chart: [Chart Example](http://codepen.io/ryanjgill/pen/PPyzoX)

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    }...
```

Comment: I don't think that there is any such option. [here](https://gist.github.com/smehan/efa41c974df38d78db3f) is a pretty comprehensive cheatsheet of all the options.

Comment: Yea, I was unable to find anything in their docs. Only information about the type of zoom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `chart.zoom` function is available (but not intended for this use), but normally takes quite a few parameters from a drag-event. Faking it upon chart creation could at minimum be done like this:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    // ...
}, function() {
    this.zoom({
        xAxis: [{ min: 25, max: 30, axis: this.xAxis[0] }], 
        yAxis: [{ min: 0, max: 300, axis: this.yAxis[0] }]
    });
});
```

See [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojJMxB) for an example. If you do a manual selection I've logged the original input that function would take.